# An inequality due to Van der Corput

Tags: inequality, hyperbolic-functions

Let $x,y>0$ then prove that:

$$|\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)|\geq|x-y|\sqrt{\sinh(x)\sinh(y)}.$$

I have tried to show it in a simple case when $y=x+1$ to delete terms $x-y$ then I don't differentiate because we can substitute $X=e^x$. Now we get a quartic and multiplying by $X^2$ and putting $Y=X^2$ we obtain a quadratic. Conclude is smooth now!

For the general case we can think to make $x-y$ constant but unfortunately we cannot do the same things as above.

How to show it? And then how to show it without derivative if possible?

Thanks you.

Edit :

As user Gary make a nice answer I complete it to show it without differentiation :

We want to show $x,y>0$ :

$$\sinh(x)\sinh(y)\leq \sinh^2\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$$

Using $X=e^x$ and $Y=e^y$ the inequality after some algebraic manipulation is :

$$\frac{X}{Y}+\frac{Y}{X}-2\geq 0$$

See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sqrt%28xy%29-1%2Fsqrt%28xy%29%29%C2%B2-%28x-1%2Fx%29%28y-1%2Fy%29) to convince you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left| {\cosh x - \cosh y} \right| & = 2\left| {\sinh \left( {\frac{{x - y}}{2}} \right)\sinh \left( {\frac{{x + y}}{2}} \right)} \right|
\\ &
 \ge 2\frac{{\left| {x - y} \right|}}{2}\left| {\sinh \left( {\frac{{x + y}}{2}} \right)} \right| = \left| {x - y} \right|\left| {\sinh \left( {\frac{{x + y}}{2}} \right)} \right| \\& \ge \left| {x - y} \right|\sqrt {\sinh x\sinh y} 
\end{align*}
since $|w|\leq|\sinh w|$ and $\sinh$ is log-concave on the positive axis.

Comment: Just a question can we prove the log concavity without differentiation ? Thanks !

Comment: I do not see a simple way to do it without differentiation.

Comment: See my edit Gary in fact it's simple !:-)