# About the inequality $\int_{-\infty}^{0}\left(\cosh\left(x\right)-1\right)^{x}dx<\pi$

Tags: inequality, improper-integrals, hyperbolic-functions, constants

Found with Desmos.
Claim

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}\left(\cosh\left(x\right)-1\right)^{x}dx<\pi$$

---

---

I cannot show it currently and before I tried the Van der Corput inequality:

Let $x,y>0$ then:

$$|\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)|\geq|x-y|\sqrt{\sinh(x)\sinh(y)}.$$

A proof can be found here [An inequality due to Van der Corput](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4233706/an-inequality-due-to-van-der-corput)

Unforntunately it's really not sufficient and bad because we work on the negative axis.

---

Edit :

Another attempt wich fails : With the Gary'substitution and :

Let $x>0$ then :

$$\sinh(x)\frac{1}{x}<\cosh(x)$$

Unfortunately the integral below (see comment Gary) converges if we use the lower bound above but it's greater than $\pi$ .

---

How to show the claim?

Thanks.

Ps: The inequality is not tight.

Comment: With a change of integration variable you can make it an integral along the positive axis: $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{dx}}{{(\cosh x - 1)^x }}} .
$$ However, the Van der Corput inequality is trivial when $y=0$.

Comment: @Gary oh well...Have you an idea to tackle it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Remark*: Although we get a closed-form bound (in terms of elementary functions), the solution is still quite complicated.

---

We have
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 (\cosh x - 1)^x\, \mathrm{d}x 
= \int_0^\infty 2^{-x}\left(\sinh\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-2x}\,\mathrm{d} x = \int_0^\infty 2^{1 - 2x}(\sinh x)^{-4x}\, \mathrm{d}x.$$

---

*Fact 1*: $\int (\sinh x)^{-5}\, \mathrm{d}x = 
-\frac{\cosh x}{4\sinh^4 x} + \frac{3\cosh x}{8\sinh^2 x} - \frac{3}{8}\ln\frac{\mathrm{e}^x + 1}{\mathrm{e}^x - 1} + C$.

*Fact 2*: $\int (\sinh x)^{-4}\, \mathrm{d}x =
-\frac{\cosh x}{3\sinh^3 x} + \frac{2\cosh x}{3\sinh x} + C$.

*Fact 3*: $\sinh x \ge x + \frac16 x^3$ for all $x\in [0, 1]$.

Let $T(f(x),a,n)$ denote the $n$-th order Taylor approximation of $f(x)$ at $x = a$.

*Fact 4*: For all $x\in [0, 1]$,
$(1 + x^2/6)^{-4x} \le T((1 + x^2/6)^{-4x}, 0, 12)$.
(*Proof*: Take logarithm, then take derivative and the 2nd derivative.)

*Fact 5*: For all $x\in [0, 1]$,
$2^{-2x} \le T(2^{-2x}, 0, 6)$.
(*Proof*: Take logarithm, then take derivative.)

*Fact 6*: For all $u \in [-1, 0]$,
$\mathrm{e}^{-4u} \le T(\mathrm{e}^{-4u}, 0, 8) + \frac{512}{315}u^8$.
(*Proof*: Take logarithm, then take derivative.)

---

First, using Fact 1, we have
\begin{align*}
 \int_{5/4}^\infty 2^{1 - 2x}(\sinh x)^{-4x}\, \mathrm{d}x
 &\le \int_{5/4}^\infty 2^{1 - 2\cdot \frac{5}{4}}(\sinh x)^{-4\cdot \frac{5}{4}}\, \mathrm{d}x \\
 &= -\frac{\sqrt2}{4}\left(-\frac{\cosh (5/4)}{4\sinh^4 (5/4)} + \frac{3\cosh (5/4)}{8\sinh^2 (5/4)} - \frac{3}{8}\ln\frac{\mathrm{e}^{5/4} + 1}{\mathrm{e}^{5/4} - 1}\right)\\
 &< \frac{3}{500}.
\end{align*}

Second, using Fact 2, we have
\begin{align*}
 \int_1^{5/4} 2^{1 - 2x}(\sinh x)^{-4x}\, \mathrm{d}x
 &\le \int_1^{5/4} 2^{1 - 2\cdot 1}(\sinh x)^{-4\cdot 1}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
 &= -\frac{\cosh (5/4)}{6\sinh^3 (5/4)} + \frac{\cosh (5/4)}{3\sinh (5/4)} - \left(-\frac{\cosh 1}{6\sinh^3 1} + \frac{\cosh 1}{3\sinh 1}\right)\\
 &< \frac{3}{80}.
\end{align*}

Third, using Facts 3-6, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\int_0^1 2^{1 - 2x}(\sinh x)^{-4x}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
 \le\,& \int_0^1 2^{1 - 2x}(x + x^3/6)^{-4x}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
 =\, & \int_0^1 2^{1 - 2x}(1 + x^2/6)^{-4x}x^{-4x}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
 \le\, & 2\int_0^1 T(2^{-2x}, 0, 6) \, T((1 + x^2/6)^{-4x}, 0, 12)
 \, \left[T(\mathrm{e}^{-4u}, 0, 8) + \frac{512}{315}u^8\right]_{u = x\ln x}\, \mathrm{d} x \tag{1}\\
 <\, & 1549/500.
\end{align*}
*Note*: The integral in (1) admits a closed form
$a_0 + a_1\ln 2 + a_2\ln^2 2 + a_3\ln^3 2 + a_4\ln^4 2 + a_5\ln^5 2 + a_6\ln^6 2$
where $a_i$'s are all rational numbers.

Thus, we have $\int_0^\infty 2^{1 - 2x}(\sinh x)^{-4x}\, \mathrm{d}x
< \frac{3}{500} + \frac{3}{80} + 1549/500 < \pi$.

We are done.

Comment: Impressive ! Let me the time to read it !

Comment: @ErikSatie It is not a nice proof. I hope to see nice proofs.